# Is there a way to prevent the initial state from loading when my angularjs app starts up?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Background**

My app needs to make a request to the server to verify whether or not the user has an authenticated session, before the first state is loaded. As depending on on the url, the user may need to be redirected to the login page.

i.e if the initial url is `myapp.com/#/profile` and the user doesn't have a pre-existing authenticated session, they'll be redirected to `myapp.com/#/login`

**Problem**

I have logic in place to deal with this situation, but immediately after the session data request is made to the server and before it completes, the initial state change is triggered and the page loads and displays, before the server responds

**Possible Solutions**

1) I'm using django as my backend, so could just remove the initial server request from the app and pass the data direct to the app in the django template. Either through

- ng-init of the main controller - although i've read that this is a
  bad idea, as it's not it's intended usage
- Or in a script tag in the django template - which i'm loathe to
  do, as i'd rather keep all my application logic seperate in js files

2) Listen for the initial $stateChangeStart, cancel it and then call $state.reload() once the server requests completed

**Question**

It would seem to me to be a fairly common requirement to fulfill certain criteria before the initial state change occurs, so i'm wondering if i've missed something in the docs and there's already an inbuilt way to deal with this scenario?

Or is there a way to deactivate the $urlRouterProvider/$stateProvider to prevent the initial state change from occurring?

Comment: Depending on how you're doing routing in Angular, use the `resolve` property for routes: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider - I use this for exactly what you're talking about. In the `resolve` callback, I make an AJAX request to my server to get user info from the session. If nothing is returned, that means they're not authenticated and I reject the promise that is used in the `resolve`

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I'd considered that, but wouldn't it mean having to  add the same function to every states resolve property?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I think so, yes. You can declare the function once, and then use it for all your routes (pass the reference) - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing i suppose. It would just seem cleaner if there were a way to add a generic resolve to the routeProvider itself - which gets called for all routes - rather than having to add it to every route in the config. And then maybe a way to then remove it as well, once it's no longer needed.

Comment: I would love to hear someone else's solution, because the use of `resolve` is all I could find in my extensive searching when I needed a solution for something like this. It seems like any form of listening for a state change (or whatever) doesn't allow you to "resume" or "cancel" (only "cancel").

Comment: Yeah i think you're probably right, this is the best way to go. I'm just a bit OCD... I think you can use `$route.reload()` or `$state.reload()` (although it mentions a possible bug in the ui.router docs) to resume the change

Comment: I'm a bit OCD too, and this solution bothers me for that reason. I may be wrong, but I think using `$route.reload` **after** canceling a route would just reload the current one, not the canceled one. I may be wrong though

Comment: Ahh, i see what you mean. For me that's not a problem, as my session data will be set, so my redirect logic will kick in to deal with it

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that (my app isn't structured in such a way). So what's the possible bug with UI router? The quick search I just did for UI router reload shows a few different ways to effectively reload the current route

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload - it just says 'bug with controllers reinstantiating right now, fixing soon'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all of your authentication logic is already inside something like `AuthService`, wouldn't it be possible to do the following?

```
// 'AuthService' injected earlier
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        // prevent navigation. don't go anywhere;
        // navigation will occur inside AuthService
        event.preventDefault();

        AuthService.setNextState(toState.name);
        AuthService.authenticateWithServer();
    }
    // proceed normally if user is already authenticated
});
```

Then, your `AuthService`:

```
app.service('AuthService', function($rootScope, $http, $state) {
    var next;

    this.setNextState = function(nextState) { next = nextState; };

    this.isAuthenticated = function() { ... };

    this.authenticateWithServer = function() {
        $http.post('/authen', { ... }).success(function(user){
            // house-keeping
            $rootScope.user = user;

            // navigate by state name
            $state.go(next);
        }).error(function(error) {
            // navigate to login screen
            $state.go('login');
        });
    };
});
```

This way, your state definition is clean, and the authentication logic is isolated in one place. You can also be sure that navigation will never take place until you have all the info you need.

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me come up with a similar solution. My problem's slightly different, as there are states that an unauthenticated user can visit

Comment: @james If it helps, you should consider accepting the answer. At least in the future people will be more inclined to click in and read this page instead of ignoring it as unanswered question.